# How to install Xfce on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: xfce

I want to install xfce on Ubuntu 14.10 and try it out. and I'd also like to keep unity launcher just in case I don't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

easily install xfce desktop by this command

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

And then logout and login

Also, note this will not remove the ubunu-desktop(unity), then all of what you want is just swapping between the different desktop managers

From your login page click on the Ubuntu icon near the place you entering your password, this would show you all Desktop managers in your system, like the pic below, so choose which one to use.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just test it, use a virtual machine.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

However, if you are sure you want to install it:

Run `sudo apt-get update`

Then `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

This should install XFCE, while keeping LightDM as the display manager. Any display manager you use, however, should retain the ability to switch environments.